The output of the "dir" command appears cascading
I'm learning PHP and I've created a routine that prints the path indicated in the text box.
The issue is that the output appears indented to the right, cascading down, instead of all lines appearing in the same position.
<html>
<body>
<form method="GET" name="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<input type="TEXT" name="cmd" autofocus id="cmd" size="80">
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Execute">
</form>
<pre>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $cmd = escapeshellcmd($_GET['cmd']);

    $output = shell_exec('dir ' . $cmd);
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>

The output would be something like this:

Could someone please tell me how to proceed or solve this? As I mentioned, I'm learning and I'm not very clear on how to fix it.

The <pre> tag honors whitespace. If you view source (don't inspect) you'll see that the whitespace in the HTML is the same as what you are seeing.

Honestly, the general solution to your specific case is to not use shell_exec at all, and instead use scandir or similar. If, however, you are trying to build a general "arbitrary shell tool", the fact that you are also doing this on Windows might cause you additional headaches beyond just the security and portability issues.

Aside: Use escapeshellarg() to escape a single argument.

He tried using escapeshellarg() without any changes.
In the end, he used scandir as Chris suggested.
With this, he can now visualize the files and directories in a sufficiently clean way.
Thank you very much, everyone.
